# How do I sort a vector in ascending order in intervals in R language?

Tags: r, sorting, vector

Suppose that I have a vector named x = c(3,2,1,2,1,3,1,3,2). I need help in an algorithm that will help me sort the values in x in ascending order like this (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3).

Comment: What defines your groups? Position within the vector, or something else?

Comment: Yes the positions within the vector

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
x <- c(3,2,1,2,1,3,1,3,2)

as.vector(apply(matrix(x, nrow = 3), 2, sort))
```